# Alguem poderia me explicar o termo "Specification pattern", aplicada em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-pattern, comparação, extjs

Fiz algumas pesquisas na net, encontrei esse [site](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/structuring-and-validating-business-rules-in-javascript-fbaa1019902a) com valiosas informações.
Trabalho muito com condicionais usando javascript, veja um trecho da minha função que recebe radiogroup como parametro e verifica se foi selecionado sim ou não, realizando assim as devidas tarefas:

```
    var habilitarCampo3 = function(obj,  selectedRadio)
{
    if(selectedRadio.inputValue == "NAO"){
        Ext.getCmp('comJustificativaAviso').setVisible(true);
        if (iAtividade == 7)
        {
            TransitionData2Form.insertMandatory('comJustificativaAviso','Justifique o não desconto do Aviso Prévio!');

        }
    }
    else{
        Ext.getCmp('comJustificativaAviso').setVisible(false);
        TransitionData2Form.removeMandatory('comJustificativaAviso');
        Ext.getCmp('comJustificativaAviso').setValue(Ext.getCmp('procedeJuridico').getValue().inputValue);

    }
};
```

Às vezes, essa código fica no próprio objeto radiogroup, vejam:

```
checkSolicitacoesRealizadas = new Ext.form.RadioGroup
         ({
     width:600,
     fieldLabel:'Solicitações foram realizadas',
     labelSeparator: '?',
     id:'checkSolicitacoesRealizadas',
     value:'ZERO',
      listeners:
              {
                change: function(obj, selectedRadio)
                  {
                    if (selectedRadio.inputValue == "NAO")
                     {
                      alert('É obrigatório a geração das solicitações');
                      Ext.getCmp('checkSolicitacoesRealizadas').setValue('ZERO');
                      }

                  }
              },
     items: [
     {boxLabel: '<b style="color:green;" >Sim</b>', name: 'checkSolicitacoesRealizadas-op', inputValue: "SIM"},
     {boxLabel: '<b style="color:green;" >Sim</b>', hidden:true, name: 'checkSolicitacoesRealizadas-op', inputValue: "ZERO"},
     {boxLabel: '<b style="color:red;" >Não</b>', name: 'checkSolicitacoesRealizadas-op', inputValue: "NAO"}
     ]
         });
```

Aqui uma das centenas de condicionais do meu código:

```
 if (Ext.getCmp('tipoRescisao').getValue() == 02 && 
              Ext.getCmp('tipoSolicitacao').getValue().inputValue == 'desligamento')
          {
          if (Ext.getCmp('dataInicioAvisoPrevio').getValue() == '')
              {
                      msgErro += "\n É Obrigatório [Data Início Aviso Prévio]!";
                  }
                }
```

Minha pergunta é: Existe algum Design Patterns que trata uma melhor forma de organizar estruturas condicionais, realizando algum aproveitamento código durante a comparação do valor do campo? Eu queria organizar uma estrutura dinâmica e inteligente para realizar as comparações de valor dos campos do formulário. Espero ter sido claro na pergunta. Qualquer dúvida eu melhoro a pergunta, isso é muito importante pra mim.

Comment: Eu esta pronto para sinalizar como "baseada em opniões" pela parte que você diz "melhor forma de organizar estruturas" mas acho que podemos aproveitar essa pergunta, basta alterar essa parte para "poderiam me apresentar alguns design Partner" para que você mesmo possa ver as formas "diferentes" de se fazer a mesma coisa, e dai p/ frente você escolhe a que você achar mais conveniente ;)

Comment: "Existe algum Design Patterns que trata uma melhor forma de organizar estruturas condicionais, ...." Obrigado pela atenção. Acho que essa pergunta realmente válida. Quando digo "Organizar Melhor", eu busco um conceito que trate o uso excessivo de if's, preciso de uma alternativa. A sua resposta não contempla essa questão dos if's.

Comment: A questão do if, é só fazer uma chamada para uma função de fora do objeto e fazer todas as validações em outra função, os if não estão na resposta, mas o conceito de chamada de função sim

Comment: Existe a biblioteca jQuery, o Angular JS e o React que podem te ajudar bastante nesse sofrimento todo. E tem o site do Mozilla que pode oferecer muito mais respostas para a tua pergunta: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou mostrar a forma de como eu trabalho os meus arquivos javascript:

```
var ctCompra = {};                                                          // NOVO PADRAO DE DESENVOLVIMENTO        

ctCompra.eventos = function(){                                                      // FUNCAO EVENTOS
    $('#novaautorizacao').button().click(function(){ctCompra.novoFornec();});       // BOTAO NOVA AUTORIZACAO        
    $('#dialog-confirm').hide();                                                    // ESCONDER TELA DE AVISO
    $('button').hide();                                                             // ESCONDER TODOS OS BOTOES
    $("#btEncerrar").button().click(function(){ ctCompra.encerrar(); });            // BOTAO ENCERRAR
    $("#btVoltar").button().click(function(){ ctCompra.retornar(); });              // BOTAO VOLTAR
    $("#mostratodos").button().click(function(){ ctCompra.mostraTodos(); });        // BOTAO MOSTRAR TODOS 
    $("#mostrapendente").button().click(function(){ ctCompra.mostraPendente(); });  // BOTAO MOSTRAR DEPENDENTE        
    $('input:text').setMask();                                                      // CONFIG DE MASKARAS NOS INPUT
    $('#novaautorizacao').show();                                                   // BOTAO NOVA AUTORIZACAO MOSTRAR        
    $('#valor_final').change(function(){ ctCompra.selectPgt(); });                  // CARREGAR PARCELAS
    ctCompra.ajusteSpinner();                                                       // DEPENDENCIA DE EVENTOS
    ctCompra.ajusteTela();                                                          // CHAMADA DA FUNCAO AJUSTE DE TELA
    ctCompra.colorirTr();                                                           // CHAMADA DA FUNCAO COLORIR TR        
};
```

Vamos lá, declarei uma variável chamada **ctCompra** ela funciona como um objeto dinamico, eu coloco o nome do atributo e faço ele receber uma função, ex: *ctCompra.eventos = function(){...* quando eu chamar *ctCompra.eventos()* tudo o que estiver dentro daquela function será chamada, observe que por "organização" meus eventos de tela estão todos ai, e ai dentro dessa função outras 3 funções sendo chamadas:

- ctCompra.ajusteSpinner();
- ctCompra.ajusteTela();
- ctCompra.colorirTr();

E logo abaixo desse código eu escrevo elas assim:

```
ctCompra.ajusteSpinner=function(){                                                  // FUNCAO AJUSTE SPINNER
    ctCompra.parcelas = $('#qtd_parcelas').spinner();                               // BOTAOZINHOS DE INCREMENTAR E DECREMENTAR NO CANTO DO FIELD        
    $('.ui-spinner').removeClass('ui-corner-all').css('float','right');             // STYLE
    $('.ui-spinner').css('margin-right','10px');                                    // STYLE
    ctCompra.parcelas.spinner('disable');                                           // DEFAULT DESABILITADO POIS COMEÇA COM PGT À VISTA QTD=1
    ctCompra.parcelas.spinner({min: 1, max:99});                                    // NÃO ACEITAR VALORES NEGATIVOS NEM ZERO
    $('#select-forma-pgt').change(function(){ ctCompra.selectPgt(); });             // EVENTO SELECIONAR À VISTA OU A PRAZO
    $('.ui-spinner-button').click(function(){ ctCompra.evParcelas(); });            // EVENTO DE CLICAR NA QTD PARCELAS        
};

ctCompra.ajusteTela=function(){                                                     // FUNÇAO AJUSTE DE TELA
    $('#fieldset-menu').css('height','670px');                                      // TELA CONTROLE COMPRA
    $('#fieldset-menu').css('margin','0 70px 10px 0');                              // TELA CONTROLE COMPRA
    $('#div-compromisso').css('padding-top','12px');                                // TELA MENU DE OPÇOES        
};

ctCompra.colorirTr=function(){                                                      // FUNCAO COLORIR TR
    $(".a").mouseover(function(){ $(this).addClass('hover'); });                    // EVENTO MOUSEOVER COLOCAR COR NA TR
    $(".a").mouseout(function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover'); });                  // EVENTO MOUSEOUT RETIRAR COR DA TR  
};
```

Então sempre que você precisar programar dentro de um "objeto" para não ficar misturando a programação faça um trecho de código que chame uma função de fora para não ficar com um monte de function(){... uma dentro da outra.

Comment: A questão de "programar dentro de objetos" até que está clara para mim. Infelizmente não consegui a melhor forma de trabalhar com estruturas condicionais. Esse site https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/no-more-ifs-alternatives-to-statement-branching-in-javascript/ me ajudou a ter uma visão diferente. De qualquer forma, obrigado à todos.

Answer (score 2):

sugiro que você pare bastante pra refletir sobre seu código e tente separar as responsabilidades usando os conceitos de OO, não há problema algum em usar Specification no javascript uma vez que Specification é um padrão de projeto "abstrato" diremos assim, Specification seria uma espécie de filosofia ao invés de uma tecnologia de alguma linguagem específica, compreende ?

No entanto fica difícil como responder sua pergunta de forma eficiente, uma vez que é necessária mais informações sobre o que você está fazendo.

se é uma aplicação inteirinha em javascript, se está usando javascript como orientado a objeto ou eventos. se é uma aplicação em .NET ou Java enfim,

eu por exemplo uso specification pattern no .net junto ao Domain Driven Design, e as specifications ficam separadas bonitinhas na camada de domínio que disparam uma fila de mensagem com uma arquitetura envolvendo n-layer, até chegar na web view.

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários Design Pattern que servem para melhorar de alguma forma estrutura condicionais. Nos seus códigos de exemplo acredito que pattern mas se adeque para trazer um melhor intendimento dessas estrutruas seria o MVC Pattern ou uma de suas variações.